# html5 tags compatibility with .jsp file

Tags: spring, html, jsp, struct

While writing a .jsp file, can i include all the html5 tags in it for ex(audio, video etc.)? Does structs and springs support html5 tags when integrated with jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - I use HTML5 with my Spring + JSP web apps fine. IntelliJ IDEA has no problems either. Just make sure you use the proper HTML 5 declaration at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```